# Selenium element properties: Selected vs Enabled vs Displayed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation

I recently tried to locate an element.

I was unable to identify an **xpath** and after putting a list in a loop.
I noticed that for some elements `isDisplayed()` returned `false`, but `isEnabled()` `true`. How is it possible?

**Could it be that the element was hidden somewhere on the background, but still enabled?**

By the way, in my perception "`enabled`" is when you can bring it under focus, right? And also, for all elements where `isDisplayed()` returned `false`, `isSelected()` also returned `false`.

Am I right that if `isDisplayed()` returns `false`, `isSelected()` can never return `true` and it can only return true if `isEnabled()` returns `true`?

Answer (score 4):

No, enabled means that it's not disabled (by means of the [`disabled` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) or similar). Of course, any element that is enabled may or may not be visible (which is governed by the CSS `Display` style).
Per the JAVA documentation for `isEnabled`:

> Is the element currently enabled or not? This will generally return
>   true for everything but disabled input elements.

If you want a combination of both visible and enabled, use [the ExpectedCondition `elementToBeClickable`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java)

For `isSelected`, the documentation says the following. So if you have asked this property on other elements, you should always get the same value.

> Determine whether or not this element is selected or not. This
>   operation only applies to input elements such as checkboxes, options
>   in a select and radio buttons.

Also, you can have hidden dropdowns where a (default) value has been selected. So pretty much any combination of these three properties is possible.